# Find the least integral value of $t$ for which the roots of equation $x^2 + 2(t+1)x + 9t -5=0$ are unequal negative numbers.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

My attempt at the answer starts with $(x+p)(x+q)$. And then I got $pq=9t-5$ and $p+q= 2t-2$. Immediately I thought the smallest value for $t$ could be $5$. But when I plug that value into the second equation the results do not match. So then I started using the trial and error method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quadratic equation has distinct roots if its discriminant is positive; it has two negative roots if, besides the condition on the discriminant, its coefficients are positive (note that your equation has $1$ as the coefficient of the $x^2$ term).

Indeed, if $p$ and $q$ are negative, their sum is negative and their product is positive. If you write the polynomial as $(x-p)(x-q)=x^2-(p+q)x+pq$, the condition on the coefficients is clear. Also the converse holds, by the same decomposition.

So you have
$$
\begin{cases}
4(t+1)^2-4(9t-5)>0\\
2(t+1)>0\\
9t-5>0
\end{cases}
$$
which should lead you to the desired value for $t$.

Comment: What coefficient do you mean? How does the sign of x squared affect the roots?

Comment: Wait what isn't it x+p? If the root is negative.

Comment: Why isn't the first equation being taken square root of?

Comment: @user11355 The square root of the discriminant is used to *compute* the roots, but the discriminant $(b^2-4ac)$ should be non negative in order that the roots exist in the real numbers.

Comment: @user11355 If $p$ is a root of a polynomial, then the polynomial is divisible by $x-p$. Whether $p$ is positive or negative is irrelevant.

Comment: You mean p and q can be negative numbers themselves regardless of their signs?

Comment: @user11355 Yes; when $p$ is used to denote a number, it can be *any* number, positive, negative, or zero.